# Can I use Salesforce custom label from sales cloud in SFMC Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, customlabel, sales-cloud

Can I use Salesforce custom label from the sales cloud in SFMC Journey?
we have connected the two orgs with the Marketing cloud connector.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. The connector only fetches data from Salesforce object, not metadata.

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can create an object in Salesforce or a DE in SFMC and load it manually.

Comment: @cloudDot, a work around can be create a Salesforce object and pull the labels which you have wanted and create as a record for that object. Post that you pull the object from connector. Let me know if this helps.